# A question about simply-connected homogeneous compact complex manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, lie-groups, kahler-manifolds

A result of Borel-Remmert in 1961/1962 published in Math. Ann. states that a compact homogeneous Kähler manifold must be the product of a complex torus and a projective-rational manifold. This implies that a simply-connected compact homogeneous Kähler manifold has nonzero Euler characteristic.

My question is, if a simply-connected compact homogeneous complex manifold has nonzero Euler characteristic, can we conclude that it admits a Kähler metric? Of course, if so, it must be a projective-rational manifold by the above-mentioned result. Or is there any counterexample?

It seems that the results of a 1954 paper of H.C. Wang published in Amer. J. Math. should be related to this question. But I cannot obtain the answer from this paper.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: There are many non-simply connected examples, e.g., Iwasawa manifolds.  By the classification of complex Lie groups, I believe (but should double-check) that every compact, simply-connected, homogeneous complex manifold is projective and Fano.

Comment: There are homogeneous complex structures on $S^{2n-1}\times S^{2m-1}$ (Calabi-Eckmann manifolds), so not every homogeneous compact simply-connected complex manifold is projective.

Comment: Indeed the Calabi-Eckmann manifolds are not K\"ahler, because they have $b_2=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it appears to be true. An argument is written up in a recent preprint by Ping Li:

Nonnegative Hermitian holomorphic vector bundles and Chern numbers https://arxiv.org/pdf/1702.01701.pdf

> Theorem 4.6.
>   Suppose $M^n$ is a compact connected homogeneous complex manifold. Then
>   we have the following implications:
>
> The Chern number $c_1^n\neq 0 \Leftrightarrow$ Some Chern numbers of $M$ is nonzero $\Rightarrow$ $M$ is a projective algebraic manifold